# Firebase duplicate tableView when new date is added, updated or deleted

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swift3, xcode8

Whenever I add new data to Firebase or update the data in the Firebase console, my `tableView` data duplicates. The udemy tutorial I've followed never showed how to solve the issue. A [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=firebase%20new%20data%20duplicate%20tableview&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=FzFuWNDhD9Lj8we1iJbwCQ) brought up my problem but non seemed to explain the root of the problem; I after the root of the issue and not just an answer. I'm learning as I go along but this one bugs me.

One answer mentioned the use of `self.members.removeAll()` but Im using Swift 3, where to put that and why?

My issue relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445569/cell-is-duplicated-multiple-times-when-posting-to-firebase) but that answer seemed vague and not really an answer. I have a `configureCell()` but what should be added?

I upvote most of my question's answers when someone explains and just adding an answer. What is happening and why, please? Do I need to reload/remove something in:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell{...}
```

**Edited:**

```
var expenses = [Expense]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return expenses.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let  expense = expenses[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expenseFeedCell") as? ExpenseFeedCell {
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.configureCell(expense: expense)
            return cell
        } else {
            return ExpenseFeedCell()
        }

    }
```

**And the Expense Class:**

```
class Expense {

    // Private variables
    private var _date: Double!
    private var _type: String!
    private var _amount: Double!
    private var _notes: String!
    private var _expenseId: String!


    // Setting up the getteres
    var type: String {
        return _type
    }

    var date: Double {
        return _date
    }

    var amount: Double {
        return _amount
    }

    var notes: String {
        return _notes
    }

    var expenseId: String {
        return _expenseId
    }

    init(type: String, date: Double, amount: Double, notes: String) {
        self._type = type
        self._date = date
        self._amount = amount
        self._notes = notes
    }

    init(expenseId: String, expenseData: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self._expenseId = expenseId

        if let type = expenseData["type"] as? String {
            self._type = type
        }

        if let date = expenseData["date"] as? Double {
            self._date = date
        }

        if let amount = expenseData["amount"] as? Double {
            self._amount = amount
        }

        if let notes = expenseData["notes"] as? String {
            self._notes = notes
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the firebase method you use to read data is called each time there is a new entry, you should remove the content of your data array before adding data on it.

So in the firebase method, start by having an empty array. After that you can treat with the snapchot and fill this same array.

Add a `self.tableView.reloadData()` to reload the view with new data in this array

Comment: Hi. Please explain, I do not have a `self.member` is my code. Do I need to update `cellForRowAt`? The link in "My issue relates to this" pretty much sums up my code?

Comment: How many numbers returns numberOfRowsInSection when your data are duplicated ?

Comment: If I currently have 3, 3 return (a duplicate) making it 6, if I only update. 7 if I post a new data.

Comment: Do you mean to post `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132414/discussion-between-grifas-and-sylar).